# Conjunction and multiple return values

Tags: ruby

I have validation methods that return a two-element array of `true`/`false` and a string. An example is:

```
def check_length(name)
  if(name.length > 50)
    return false, "Length more than 50"
  else
    return true, ""
  end
end
```

I'm trying to check for multiple methods of this kind. I wrote a code like the following:

```
def validate
  value, message =
  check_length(name) &&
  is_valid(id) &&
  is_any_mismatch(name,id) &&
  is_valid(name) &&
  ...
end
```

I expect `value` to take the `true`/`false` and `message` the string value. If `check_length` returns `false`, the second method `is_valid` should not be evaluated.

But for the code above, even if `check_length` returns `false`, `is_valid` is evaluated, and `value` is overridden by the return value of `is_valid`.

How can we break execution if the first condition is `false`, and return from `validate` function? i.e short circuit evaluation should work with two return values.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question from description. Can you show both `check_length` and `is_valid` methods?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "return two values". Do they each return two values (i.e., perhaps as an array, four elements in total), or do they return two values together (which would not be informative because only the value of `is_valid` matters)?

Comment: return true," Name length is more than 50 chars". This is how i'm returning

Comment: Short circuit evaluation doesn't seem to work if multiple values are returned. how to achieve that in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is an array, so it is never going to be falsy (even if its first element if `false`). This means that you have to construct the logic the other way using disjunction, not conjunction. A detected error would return an array (i.e., truthy value), and lack of error would be `nil`. Then finally, you return an array as a default that has `true`.

```
def check_length(name)
  if(name.length > 50)
    return false, "Length more than 50"
  else
    return nil
  end
end

def validate
  check_length(name) ||
  is_valid(id) ||
  is_any_mismatch(name,id) ||
  is_valid(name) ||
  ... ||
  [true, ""]
end
```

This will return a two-element array that has `true`/`false` as the first element and the message as the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot sawa.. From yesterday i was trying but couldnot find a way